# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm new to javascript and am working on a project that needs to take an array of numbers and counts the amount of each type of number (positives, negatives, zeros) and then return the counts in another array. So far I've tried the below code:

```js
let negatives = 0;
let zeros = 0;
let positives = 0;

function counter(numbersArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2]) {
  var returnArray = [negatives, zeros, positives]

  for (x = 0; x < numbersArray.length; x++) {
    if (numbersArray[x] < 0) {
      negatives++;
    } else if (numbersArray[x] === 0) {
      zeros++;
    } else {
      positives++;
    }
  }

  return returnArray;
}
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
```

The code returns this after calling it 3 times:

```
counter();
(3) [0, 0, 0]
counter();
(3) [2, 3, 4]
counter();
(3) [4, 6, 8]
```

I adjusted it to this:

```js
var numbersArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2];

function counter(numbersArray) {
  var negatives = 0;
  var zeros = 0;
  var positives = 0;

  var returnArray = [negatives, zeros, positives]

  for (x = 0; x < numbersArray.length; x++) {
    if (numbersArray[x] < 0) {
      negatives++;
    } else if (numbersArray[x] === 0) {
      zeros++;
    } else {
      positives++;
    }
  }

  return returnArray;
}
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
```

But get the following error when calling:

```
counter();
VM82:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at counter (<anonymous>:14:34)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I understand that it means that my array is undefined, I don't understand why though because I am defining it in the first line.  Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to call with the parameter: `counter(numbersArray);`

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably in this line

```
for (x = 0; x < numbersArray.length; x++) {
```

`numbersArray.length` is causing this error, and that is probably because `numbersarray` is not initialized.

If you call the `counter` function with no parameters, this would happen. You will need to pass an array as a parameter to the `counter` function, like this:

```
counter([1,2,2,3,4,5]);
```

or have a default value like your first example.

Answer (score 0):

you need to re position your returnArray:

```js
var numbersArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2];

function counter(numbersArray) {
  var negatives = 0;
  var zeros = 0;
  var positives = 0;

 
  for (x = 0; x < numbersArray.length; x++) {
    if (numbersArray[x] < 0) {
      negatives++;
    } else if (numbersArray[x] === 0) {
      zeros++;
    } else {
      positives++;
    }
  }
  
   var returnArray = [negatives, zeros, positives]


  return returnArray;
}

console.log(counter(numbersArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help.  I adjusted it to this:

```
function counter (numbersArray = []){

let negatives = 0;
let zeros = 0;
let positives = 0;


    for (x = 0; x < numbersArray.length; x++){
        if (numbersArray[x] < 0) {
        negatives ++;
        } else if (numbersArray[x] === 0){
        zeros ++;
        } else {
        positives++;
        }
var returnArray = [negatives, zeros, positives]
       }

    return returnArray;
      }
```

This allows me to pass parameters as needed when calling the function such as:
counter([1,2,3,0,4,0,0,0,-1,-2]);